# C# Winforms - Toggle viability states from one usercontrol to another usercontrol?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have attached an example of what I am trying to accomplish with my code below. If possible could someone write a snippet or explain how this could work? I have tried several different ways and none of my attempts have panned out (I keep getting scope errors or that the usercontrol is unrecognized).

Currently trying to get UserControl1.Button1 to toggle the visibility state on UserControl2.

Hierarchy:

1. Form1

   1. UserControl1

      1. Button1
   2. UserControl2

      1. Button1

I can get variations of this to work shown below, but usercontrol to usercontrol seems to require some extra steps. Help!

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void HIDE2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userControl21.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Not the right way to do it.  Raise an event instead so the form can take appropriate action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hans-passant pointed out.

The use of events gives us an easy way to employ the observer pattern.

Implement a custom `Event` In `UserControl1` and invoke this event (notify the observers about a change) when the button to hide the second control is clicked:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler HideRequested;

    ...

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HideRequested != null)
        {
            HideRequested.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

}
```

The in Form1, attach to the event by implementing an event handler:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        userControl11.HideRequested += userControl11_HideRequested;
    }

    void userControl11_HideRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userControl21.Hide();
    }
```

There are of course other ways to achieve this, but any other way will probably introduce coupling in your code. For example, this is also valid (by changing the access modifier of user control 2 to public):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (Parent as Form1).userControl21.Hide();
    }
```

You can also think of something like this: (then you don't have to change the access modifier of USerControl2 to public)

in Form1:

```
    public void HideUserControl2()
    {
        userControl21.Hide();
    }
```

And in the UserControl1 button_click:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (Parent as Form1).HideUserControl2();
    }
```

Comment: You are a god. Not only did you explain and show a snippet, you also took time to explain the alternate scenarios I can't thank you enough :).

Comment: You’re welcome. Don’t thank me, I’m happy to be able to help.

Comment: @Jeremy, by the way, you can also help me by marking this as answer if it helped you and is working. Thank you.

Comment: marked :) just out of curiosity is there a way to activate an event by defining a child? Some thing like: this.haschildren(usrcntrl___);?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, but I did not understand.Arw you asking if it was possible to raise an event when a specific condition is met?