# WinForms, sending data from Form to already existing Form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, set, setter

I have main Form with `DataGridView`. I'm opening new Form, filling text fields, and pressing button to close the window. Once the button is clicked I also want to send data from text fields to `DataGridView`.

I'm currently experimenting on one textbox. 
Form1:

```cs
public String SetLastDataGridViewFirstName
{
    set { dgvDisplay.Rows[dgvDisplay.RowCount].Cells[0].Value = value; }
}
```

Form2:

```cs
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainMenu.SetLastDataGridViewFirstName = txbAddFirstName.Text;
    this.Close();
}
```

But I'm unable to access setter. Its obvious that this implementation won't work (just showing example what I'm thinking about), but I'm unable to find working solution. All tutorials show how to send data to new Form, not already existing.

Comment: Implement an event in your "new Form", attach to this event in your main form, and raise this event from the "new Form" when the add button is clicked (and pass the data to the main form using your custom event args)

Comment: Here is a sample post (which implements this between a child control and the form): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60818033/c-sharp-winforms-toggle-viability-states-from-one-usercontrol-to-another-userc/60819514#60819514

Comment: Or use an Interface as shown here: [Child Form getting properties from multiple parent Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56165975/7444103)

Comment: I have currently solved it with workaround method, but i will check these suggestions out, thanks. I have static instance of main menu in main menu which lets me call some specific methods in any other form.